# How to make card-slider using html,css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slideshow

[image]

I want to create a card-slider. There is a total of 5 cards. # cards are visible to the screen and two are off the screen, one on the left and one on the right. The arrow icons should be used to move left and right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it
[click here][1]
[1]: https://codepen.io/alextanta/pen/mXxxgj